# View bulk operation not respecting user permissions

Tags: 8, views

- Created two content type Type-A and Type-B
- Created user role "Editor"
- Editor have access to delete only Type-A nodes but not Type-B nodes
- Created Views landing page of these nodes with bulk operation.

If I login as editor and check Views landing page bulk operation, Editor can even delete Type-B nodes, which is a strange behavior.
Ideally Editor should not see "Delete" option for Type-B nodes. Only for Type-A nodes he should see the delete options in views bulk operation dropdown.

Comment: This is a bug report and should be posted to the module Issues list. It's already been reported  [Delete when no permission to delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/1851656)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for VBO on d.o. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/1851656

Comment: Issue is in Drupal 8

Comment: Add your comment there with your 8 version. The fix will have to be ported to D8 too.